# Can we solve in O(n*log(n)) , find pairs (x,y) , x+y <= k

Tags: algorithm

Given 2 arrays X and Y of positive integers, x belongs to X and y belongs to Y, find pairs (x,y) such that x+y <= k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in `O(nlogn + m)` - where `m` is the size of the output.

```
sort array X
sort array Y
for reach element x in X:
   for each y in Y in ascending order, and while y <= k-x:
       yield (x,y)
```

Complexity of this algorithm is `O(nlogn + m)`. However, `m` itself might be quadric in `n` - for example, if `k` is very large - you will need to return all pairs, and there are `O(n^2)` of those.

Comment: What is `n` in your formula ? Do you assume both arrays have same size ?

Comment: You write `while y <= x-k` shouldn't it be ` while y <= k-x` ?

Comment: @fjardon `n` is the size of the input, so `|X|+|Y|`, basically. And regarding your second comment - yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On Stackoverflow, you asked for an algorithm to pair numbers from two
arrays that satisfy a condition. a+b <= c. But you deleted your question
before I could answer. I disagree with the guys that say it is
impossible to find the pairs in O(n*log n).

It depends on the compactnes of your output. If you choose a "good"
output format i.e. specifying pairs as regions allows you to compute the
pairs by sorting the two arrays and perform a binary search over the two
arrays. But if you're forced to write out each pair, then it is obvious
that the complexity is O(n*n).

An example:

a1 = [1,6,3,5,2,4] length a1 = l1 = 6
a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] length a2 = l2 = 6

First sort both array in n * log n

a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

compare value c = 5
l2/2 = 6/2 = 3

test a1[0] + a2[l2/2] = 1 + 4 =< 5 (true)
=> so it is true for all values less than a2[l2/2]

then we must test the values greater than a2[l2/2]
we take the midlle (l2/2+l2)/2 (median) of the right part of the array
and make the test

test a1[0] + a2[4] = 1 + 5 =< 5 (false)

because there no more element on left side we have not yet tested we
could take the result from our last test.

We can now say that the sum of element at index 0 of array a1 and each
element of array a2 up to the index 3 passes the test and print the
result [0,3].

Then we repeat that for the element at index 1 of array a1. And so on.

You have to sort two arrays in O(n*log(n))
Then print the two sorted arrays O(n)
Then perform the binary search n times => O(n*log(*))
The results are printed at the end of each binary search => O(n)

Now it's just a matter of interpreting the ouput correctly. ;-)

What do you think? Am I right or did I missed something? Can you use
that compact output?

**Answered by Peter Paul Kiefer**

Comment: Guys please don't downvote !!

Comment: Is it an answer or a part of the question?

Comment: Did you ask a question to answer it? Seems like you made an argument in hopes you got comments saying it is impossible....

Comment: It's a matter of *defining* what your algorithm is supposed to output. If it's supposed to output all the pairs (i.e. individually, which requires at least 1 bit of output per pair), which you asked for, then it's impossible. If it's supposed to output the pairs in a format which allows for them to be encoded in O(n log n) total space, then it's possible. There's also the notion of an *output-sensitive algorithm* in algorithmics, where you consider the output size as a complexity parameter *k*. In this case it is possible to design an algorithm of complexity O(n log n + k)